# Admin fonts not working after collectstatic on production

Tags: wagtail

I've put my wagtail site into production. I setup a separate static site to serve my static files. After collectstatic, everything works except fonts inside the admin site. I'm assuming it has something to do with cross site scripting as I see this in the web developer tools:

(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

It appear on all the fonts. I have pip installed django-cors-headers and set this variable:

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

However, it does not fix my issue. Any idea how to get the fonts to work in a production environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the webserver serving the static files to output a valid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, such as

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Exactly how to do this will depend on the server platform you're using. Installing django-cors-headers will not help here, as this will only add the header to requests served through Django.